# Import only class definitions from typescript module

Tags: typescript, class

I have a file in typescript that defines and exports one interface and an arbitrary number of classes that implement said interface. I want to, in another file, *without knowing ahead-of-time how many classes there are*, import all of them and call some static method for each of them.

```
export interface MyInterface {
  // various non-static, instance-level behavior
}

export class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {
  static func1(): string {
    "Something based on the identity of this class specifically";
  }

  // other non-static behavior
}

export class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
  static func1(): string {
    "Something based on the identity of this class specifically";
  }

  // other non-static behavior
}

...
```

Beyond making one floating function in this file that outputs an array containing all of the classes, is there anything I can do to import `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, etc. *without* importing the interface or any other exported variables in this file?

Comment: Why does it matter if you import the interface or anything else?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want to call `func1()` on all of the classes. If I try to do that on the interface, I'll get an error. So I want to import just the classes.

Comment: Well, if you do something like `import * as allMyStuff from './whatever';` then you can do things like `allMyStuff.MyClass1.func1()` or `allMyStuff.MyClass2.func2()`. That *also* imports `MyInterface` as `allMyStuff.MyInterface`, but you don't have to use it if you don't want to.